# GoogleやBingのような検索演算子を用いた検索機能はどのように実装できますか？

Tags: mysql, cakephp, google-search

CakePHPとMySQLを使って持っている本の情報を管理できるWEBアプリケーションを作っています。外部へ公開する予定はなく、あくまでも自分で使うものでせっかくだから作ってみようと思い作り始めました。

本の（？）情報はこんなふうになっています：

1. 発行年月
2. 著者名
3. 出版社名
4. 書名・副題
5. シリーズ名・レーベル名
6. ISBNコード
7. 本の内容・概要
8. 本の感想
9. しおり
10. 読破済みか

---

WEBアプリケーションに検索機能をつけたく、使用感はGoogleのようなスペースを入れて複数検索できたり、ダブルクォーテーションで完全一致にしたり、日時でしぼりこめたりしたいと思いました。

しかし普通にSELECT文を使うだけだとLIKE句を使った曖昧検索しか実現できず、困っています。どのようにGoogleのような検索機能を実現するのでしょうか？

Comment: MySQLの「=」を用いた完全一致検索や「AND」を用いた複数検索の仕方がわからないということですか？

Comment: @keitaro_so いえ、ANDやORはSQLで直接かかないといけませんが、検索演算子のような演算子とANDやORといったSQLの構文を結びつける方法がわからないです。

Answer (score 0):

googleのような検索を目指されているなら、「全文検索」で色々見られるのがいいかと思います。